# React derived state. Whats wrong with this code

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, conditional-rendering

Coming from angular, i would like to know what's wrong with this code. I've been told that i should use useMemo (for the fitlering part) and useRef (to store products).
I know how to do that, but i want to better understand what's wrong with this.
I have compared the number of renderings whenever searchTerm changes, and i see no difference.

```
export function ProductList({ productService }) {

  const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
  const [filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState([])

  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState(null)

  function fetchData() {
    productService
      .allProducts()
      .then((products) => {
        setProducts(products)
        setFilteredProducts(products)
      })
      .catch(console.error)
  }

  function filterProductsByName(searchTerm) {
    setSearchTerm(searchTerm)
    setFilteredProducts(filterByName(products, searchTerm))
  }

  useEffect(fetchData, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Products</h1>
      <form onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="searchTerm">Search</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="searchTerm"
            id="searchTerm"
            onChange={(e) => filterProductsByName(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
      </form>
      <div>
        {filteredProducts.map((p) => (
          <Product key={p.id} product={p} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I have compared both versions (with an without useMemo)

Comment: What is the problem you'd like a solution to? It does not seem like `useMemo` is present in the provided code.

Comment: @Wongjn that's wright. I don't think that useMemo is required. I'm using state batching (function filterProductsByName) to keep consistency after updates (user actions).  I would like to know why useMemo for filtering is so necessary.

Comment: typo: "wright" --> "right".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've been told that i should use useMemo (for the fitlering part) and useRef (to store products).

Using `useMemo` to manage derived state is good advice, using a ref to store state ... I'd question that decision. There are arguments to do this, but that's a separate discussion.

> I have compared the number of renderings whenever searchTerm changes, and i see no difference.

This ain't an issue of performance but one where people can't always keep track of *all* the possible states they may find themselves in.

This is a fairly simple component, so it's fairly simple to update the `filteredProducts` when you load the `products` and whenever the `searchTerm` changes, right? What about this:

```
.then((products) => {
    setProducts(products)
    setFilteredProducts(products)
})
```

when you load the `products` you set the `filteredProducts` to the same list. That implies that there is no `searchTerm`. So you assume that this request will happen so fast that nobody would have time to enter a `searchTerm` before you set the `products` ... not even the browsers autocomplete? And what about a slow connection?

Even in this simple code, you've already overlooked a possibility which may lead to `filteredProducts` not reflecting the `searchTerm`. It's unlikely/rare, but possible.

OK, then we'll simply `setFilteredProducts(filterByName(products, searchTerm));` and things are fine, right? But `searchTerm` in this context is a closure over the initial value, not its current value, so this doesn't work either.

Do you see the issue?

The trivial solution would be to just do

```
const filteredProducts = filterByName(products, searchTerm);
```

but this *may* compute unnecessarily often, so we `useMemo` to only recompute that list when its dependencies change:

```
const filteredProducts = useMemo(() => filterByName(products, searchTerm), [products, searchTerm]);
```

that's the "textbook solution";

Then again, **this** is a pretty simple component. Tell me, what besides loading the `products` or changing the `searchTerm` would trigger a rerender of this component? Doesn't that mean that you have to compute the `filteredProducts` on basically ever render anyways? `useMemo` is usually cheaper than the operation done within, but it ain't free.

I'd suggest you try

```
function ProductList({ productService }) {

  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState(null);

  function fetchData() {
    productService
      .allProducts()
      .then(setProducts)
      .catch(console.error);
  }

  useEffect(fetchData, [productService]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Products</h1>
      <form onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="searchTerm">Search</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="searchTerm"
            id="searchTerm"
            value={searchTerm}
            onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
      </form>
      <div>
        {filterByName(products, searchTerm).map((p) => (
          <Product key={p.id} product={p} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

One source of unnecessary rerenders may be the parent element. If that is the case you may want to consider [React.memo()](https://react.dev/reference/react/memo).

Also take a look on the topic of "controlled vs uncontrolled input" in react, maybe start here: [React - Controlled Components](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

Comment: sorry for the late reply.  one final comment, do i really need the [productService] dependency in the useEffect hook? i mean, services won't change

Comment: @stackoverflower If it really never changes, then it makes no difference. If it would ever change, then this way it will behave correctly. So if for no other reason than good practice and consistency throughout your code, leave it in the dependency array.

Answer (score 0):

There nothing wrong with your code. But in case the filtering is rather expensive, you want to avoid it to be done too often - i.e. when the page gets rerendered for other reasons than a changed filter term. At the moment, when *anything* changes at the current page, the filtering will be re-applied. These changes are not even required in your current component to happen. Keep in mind how [React rerenders](https://react.dev/learn/render-and-commit):

1. A `state` updates anywhere.
2. React renders the whole page "virtually" with all its components. This means all calculation which aren't excluded by their dependencies (by `useEffect`, `useMemo`, `useCallback`) will be executed again, even the expensive ones.
3. React compares whether the virtual rerender results in a new DOM. In that case, a "real" rerendering in the brower happens.

So,

```js
const filtered = useMemo(()=> filterByName(products, searchTerm), [products, searchTerm]);
...
setFilteredProducts(filtered);
```

ensures the filtering won't be run again as long as `searchTerm` remains the same, especially not when it's just another component which receives a state update.

But in practise, I wouldn't over-optimize here. If the list to be filtered isn't insanely long, there's no need to introduce more complicated code until it harms performance. It's even more error-prone with `useMemo`: in case you change your component at some time so it fetches new items not only initially but also time-based or based on an interaction and just adds them to the existing ones, a memorized value would suddenly bear wrong results. Long story short: avoid unnecessary complexity.

Comment: `products` is also a dependecy: `const filtered = useMemo(()=> filterByName(products, searchTerm), [products, searchTerm]);`

Comment: @Thomas Yes, but I addressed that in my last paragraph. That said, at the moment `products` changes only initially and probably before the user entered a `searchTerm`. And I'm hesitant to use an array as a dependency value, and checking all single values beats the purpose of the memo for sure. But I will add it anyway, just to avoid an issue where the loading takes longer then the user input.

Comment: so before the user enters a `searchTerm`, `useMemo` will return an empty array because only the `products` changed and not the `searchTerm`. As if no products were loaded from the backend. *"we can't really be sure whether it's identity changes or it just gets modified"* JS doesn't just magically change an objects identity or modifies it. Arrays are just regular objects.

Comment: @Thomas Regarding the filtering: I expected the filtered list to be empty if there's no `searchTerm` anyway, but I don't know how the filtering is implemented of course ... I'm imagining something like `Array.filter(...)`. But I agree it's probably okay to depend on it since we're in control of how `products` gets updated, and I've actually already rewritten my objections in the last paragraph. Thanks!

Comment: @NotX thx for your reply (i can't upvote it yet). are you sure about this ?:  **"At the moment, when anything changes at the current page, the filtering will be re-applied"**

Comment: @stackoverflower When you change the state, how should React know which components are affected? It needs to repeat everything it did before, i.e. recalculating/rerendering all displayed components. It's just a virtual rerendering, so it's rather fast, but it's still happening. You can exclude stuff from this recalculation with `useEffect` (e.g. `fetchData` won't be called again b/c of this), `useMemo` etc.

Comment: Ok, thx.  I didn't know about the virtual rendering